# Execution times of subquery for an IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there any documentation about when or how often an select statement is executed when using it in combination with **IN**?

For example:

Table **NumbersTable**

```
Numbers
1
2
3
4
5
```

Table **ObjectsTable**

```
Objects    | NumbersForObjects
Lawnmower  | 4
Hammer     | 2
Cheese     | 12
Plant      | 5
```

With the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ObjectsTable
WHERE ObjectsTable.NumbersForObjects IN (
        SELECT Numbers
        FROM NumbersTable
        )
```

Is the subquery which gets the values for the IN statement executed everytime a new row is evaluated? Or is there a possibility to store it like in an array to save execution time?

Maybe the server is also more efficient then I think it to be and it is already as fast as a native array implementation. If there is some kind of general documentation how things are implemented in the background, and somebody wouldn't mind sharing it, this would also be most welcome.

Comment: https://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/

Comment: very much appreciated, thanks. should I delete this question then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the physical semi join type (Shown in the execution plan).

If it is a hash or merge join it is only evaluated once. If it is a nested loops it will be at least partially evaluated for each outer row (but each evaluation can stop as soon as the first matching value is found for that execution).

For this last case SQL Server may sometimes add a spool to the plan to store the subquery results (and avoid having to re-evaluate from the base tables each time) if it feels that will reduce the cost sufficiently.

Comment: Your post in combination with JohnHC's commentary is sufficient for me to read into the topic. Thanks to you too. Very interesting topic for me though, as I never was aware how cool SQL really is! :D

Comment: @mayen - if you want to understand more about how the different physical join types work I recommend this blog. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/tag/joins/page/2/ start at the bottom of that page and work up

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Do you know of any other cases -- other than on a trivially small table -- where SQL Server would do a nested loop join without using an index?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - seems unlikely for the case of `IN` because it is an equi join so the other two join types will always be available and likely costed less than repeated scans of a large table.